# How can known, where is binary compiled?

Tags: build, cmake

Can I somehow find where will be binary created by add_executable placed?

I have many CMakeLists - each for every binary and one another, where I include all parts of project.

When I execute **cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release path/to/project** , than make store all binaries into directories, where their CMakeList (each to different place).

On the other hand, when I the some command without CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE all binaries are place into current directory. Can you explain me why?

I need run some of binaries, because its output is also part of package. How can we know that paths?

Comment: What host environment and toolchain are you using? Do you do in-source or out-of-source builds? If you want to get all executables in one directory you can set [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

Comment: sorry guys, problem was somewhere in files one fellow set CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE/DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have predictable locations for the binary output, then set the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target property.

On the other hand, if all you want is to run them internally during the build using `add_custom_command`, then you can just put the target name in the command and CMake will substitute the actual path.  In other contexts which accept a generator expression, you can also use `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:target>`.